# All view controllers in storyboard suddenly showing only safe zones

Tags: xcode, swift4

[image: Viewcontrollers]When I selected one of the view controllers and click to "show inspectors" (right menu) suddenly all view controllers start to get smaller and smaller. Now it's just showing part of the "safe zone" and the above menu in each one of them. I already quit and start Xcode and even start the Mac and the issue's still there.

Im on Mac Mojave 10.14 and Xcode 10.1